# javaFX MusicPlayer play sound doesn't work

Tags: java, audio, javafx, playback

I'm trying to play a sound when a button is clicked or when a new view is showing up. I wrote this method to play a sound:

```
void play_sound(String musicFile) {
        AudioClip sound = new AudioClip(new File(musicFile).toURI().toString());
        sound.play();
    }
```

and this is how I call it:

```
String musicFile = "src/resources/sounds/applause.mp3";
play_sound(musicFile);
```

I have to mention that applause.mp3 is downloaded from the web and when I play a sound from web it works. But when I want to play a sound that is recorded (for example app.mp3), it doesn't work anymore. All these files are in the same folder(sounds).

[image: sounds folder]

Comment: I assume the path to the file is incorrect. Please have a look at it. It might work if you just use "sounds/applause.mp3".

Comment: @C-Otto it looks like the downloaded file is next to the recorded file, it's unlikely that filepaths are an issue.

Comment: Have you tested both in other programs to see if they sound as expected?

Comment: @phflack I understood "from the web" as playing from a URI/URL starting with "http" or "https".

Comment: @C-Otto at first that's how I read in, then saw _"All these files are in the same folder"_

Comment: It seems *extremely* unlikely that a folder called `src` (short for "source") would be available at *runtime*. If the file is part of your project, you should be loading it as a resource anyway. Post the content of your build folder (`bin` or `build`, or perhaps `classes`).

Comment: In addition of what James_D said it will help a lot if you tell us the error you are gettin  if you got any kind  for example  MediaException or NullPointerException.

Comment: You are specifying a relative file name.  Relative file names rely on the current directory.  You have (almost) no guarantee of what the current directory is at runtime.  Try printing the absolute path of your File object, then check whether that path exists.

Comment: @phflack Yes, I tested both and they sound as expected.

Comment: @JKostikiadis there's no errors.

Comment: Can you try encoding the sound differently, running it through ffmpeg or similar, or uploading it online to a music site and then downloading it?

Answer (score -1):

Your file path should definitely start with a `/` to mark it as absolute (inside of the jar file).

Then, you should'nt use the `File` class to load resources from inside the jar file. Use

```
String path = getClass().getResource("/resources/sounds/applause.mp3")
AudioClip sound = new AudioClip(path);
```

instead.

Cheers

Comment: It is not logical that changing the pathing should work, since there is a working sound in the same directory

Comment: Uhh… right. I should've read it more closely. Maybe something is wrong with the mp3 file? If it does work in other programs, thats still no guarantee that it will in JavaFX, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes). But still, it's always better not to use the `File` class for reading files from inside a jar file, so the `getClass().getResource("/resources/…")` approach is better.